# Script that works on the computer, but doesn't works on moblie

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, click

```
<script>
$('#div a').one('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('img')[0].src = "photo.jpg";
        setTimeout($.proxy(this.click,this),5000);
    });

</script>
```

I've this script that works on the computer, but doesn't works on moblie. photo.jpg appears, but the redirect does not works, it only works if I click again on photo.jpg.
Why?

Comment: More details, what kind of mobile?

Comment: @MarkusKottländer Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that calling `this.click` in that way isn't triggering the browser's default behavior on the browser in the mobile device. Instead, you might just change the location directly:

```
$('#div a').one('click',function(e){
    var link = this.href;
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('img')[0].src = "photo.jpg";
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = link;
    },5000);
});
```